# Failure for XSL to create child elements in XML transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Trying and trying to get the following to work.  I have an XML file (serialized C# class) similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyXml xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Order>
  <Header> 
    <OrderNumber>1234</OrderNumber>
  </Header>
  <Line>
    <Sku>abc</Sku>
    <Qty>300</Qty>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Sku>xyz</Sku>
    <Qty>19</Qty>
  </Line>
</Order>
```

I need to transform this to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order Number="1234">
  <Line>
    <Product>abc</Product>
    <Quantity>300</Quantity>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Product>xyz</Product>
    <Quantity>19</Quantity>
  </Line>
</Order>
```

Making the lines children of the Order element.

Here's my most succesful attempt so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Header" >
    <Order>
      <xsl:attribute name="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Line"/>    
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template  match="Line">
    <Line>
      <Product>
        <xsl:value-of select="Sku" />
      </Product>
      <Quantity>
        <xsl:value-of select="Qty" />
      </Quantity>
    </Line>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces the incorrect xml below with multiple root nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order OrderNumber="1234" />
<Line><Product>abc</Product><Quantity>300</Quantity></Line>
<Line><Product>xyz</Product><Quantity>19</Quantity></Line>
```

There's clearly something I'm missing, but after hours of trying I cannot get the output Line elements to be children of Order at all.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Also why does the indent option only seem to affect the first level of the output xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a template matching `Header`, but within this you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="Line"/>` to get the `Line` elements, but `Line` is not a child of `Header`, so this selects nothing.

The `Line` elements in your output are actually being selected due to XSLT's [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). You don't have a template matching `Order`, so XSLT's built-in template is used, which will select both `Header` and `Line` elements under the `Order`.

One solution is is to change your the template matching `Header` to match `Order` instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Order" >
    <Order Number="{Header/OrderNumber}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Line"/>    
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template  match="Line">
    <Line>
      <Product>
        <xsl:value-of select="Sku" />
      </Product>
      <Quantity>
        <xsl:value-of select="Qty" />
      </Quantity>
    </Line>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to simplify the creation of the `Number` attribute on `Order`.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you for opening my eyes to the error that was staring me in the face all weekend.   Now have my transformation working.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using `xsl:apply-templates` on `../Line` instead of `Line` with a `mode` attribute on the template. So the changes to the template are minimal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Header" >
    <Order>
      <xsl:attribute name="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../Line" mode="sub"/>  <!-- set 'mode' to 'sub' and add '../' to XPath-->  
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template  match="Line" mode="sub">                 <!-- use template only when 'mode' is set to 'sub' -->
    <Line>
      <Product>
        <xsl:value-of select="Sku" />
      </Product>
      <Quantity>
        <xsl:value-of select="Qty" />
      </Quantity>
    </Line>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />      <!-- ignore all unmatched text() nodes -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```